# Problem using ReadAsDataContract using WCF REST Toolkit

Tags: wcf, rest, datacontractserializer

I'm a novice at serialization and I've run into a problem.   I have a REST service that returns an array of IDDescriptionPair objects.  When consuming the service, I'm using the "Paste XML as Types" VS add-in to create an object.  I'm only modifying this object to add the DataContract attribute so my namespaces match on each end.  Here's that object:

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<DataContract([Name]:="IDDescriptionPair", [Namespace]:="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Blizzard.ClassLibrary")>
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225"), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Blizzard.ClassLibrary"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute   ([Namespace]:="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Blizzard.ClassLibrary", IsNullable:=True)> _
Partial Public Class IDDescriptionPair

  Private descriptionField As String

  Private idField As Integer

  Private idFieldSpecified As Boolean

  '''<remarks/>
  <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=True)> _
  Public Property Description() As String
    Get
      Return Me.descriptionField
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      Me.descriptionField = value
    End Set
  End Property

  '''<remarks/>
  Public Property ID() As Integer
    Get
      Return Me.idField
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
      Me.idField = value
    End Set
  End Property

  '''<remarks/>
  <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()> _
  Public Property IDSpecified() As Boolean
    Get
      Return Me.idFieldSpecified
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
      Me.idFieldSpecified = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

I can call the service and deserialize the object, and it appears to work fine.  I get a list of the correct number of IDDescriptionPair objects.  The problem is that they're all blank - none of the properties are populated.

Here's the code where I consume the service:

```
Dim client As New HttpClient()
Dim endpoint As New Uri("http://bmpscnt410a/services/v1/personservices/offices/5/principals")

Using response As HttpResponseMessage = client.Get(endpoint)
  response.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful()

  Dim idp As List(Of IDDescriptionPair)
  Try
    idp = response.Content.ReadAsDataContract(Of List(Of IDDescriptionPair))()
  Catch ex As Exception
  End Try
End Using
```

I've tried using DataContractSerializer directly, but I get the same result (which is expected, I guess).   Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I should add that response.Content.ReadAsString gives me the XML that I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type which you use is a XmlSerializer type (annotated with attributes from the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace, such as `<XmlType()>`, `<XmlRoot()>` and so on). For that you'll need to use the `XmlSerializer` to deserialize that. If you include (Import) the namespace `System.Xml.Serialization`, you should get the extension methods `ReadAsXmlSerializable`, which is what you should be using to deserialize the response.